# Put background image behind ionic ion-content and ion-header

Tags: html, css, ionic2

Is it possible to have a background image for a page in an ionic 2 App that extends across the entire page including the `<ion-header>` and `<ion-content`?

I can get a background image for the content and another background image for the header but I can't get one image to cover the entire page behind both the content and the header.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a `div` first then add `ion-header` and `ion-content`.
2. Add background-image for a particular page.
3. Add property

   ```
   ion-content {
       position: initial;
   }
   ```